# PHP in userdir not working

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

My **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf** file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
        UserDir /var/zpanel/hostdata/*/public_html/
        UserDir disabled root

        <Directory /var/zpanel/hostdata/*/public_html/*>
                AllowOverride All
                Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                        # Apache <= 2.2:
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all

                        # Apache >= 2.4:
                        # Require all granted
                </Limit>
                <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                        # Apache <= 2.2:
                        Order deny,allow
                        Deny from all

                        # Apache >= 2.4:
                        #Require all denied
                </LimitExcept>
        </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

And file **/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf**

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    # Deny access to raw php sources by default
    # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
    # only in specific virtual host or directory
   Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
# Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
<FilesMatch "^\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml|ps)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default
#
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.


#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /var/zpanel/hostdata/*/public_html/*>
#        php_admin_value engine On
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

But php not working when in accessing web site via userdir. 
**www.example.com/~admin**
When i access via domain then it works. I have zPanel installed

Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Comment: You haven't said which version of Apache this is despite the repeated hints in the config that 2.2 is different from 2.4

Comment: I forgot to mention that. Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

Comment: If you use Apache 2.4 perhaps you shouldn't use the directives tagged as "Apache <= 2.2" :-?

Comment: I tried to delete this few lines and it is the same

Answer (score 5):

In my `/etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.0.conf` I have this section

```
# Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default   
#                                                                  
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines 
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it  
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.                      
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>                                           
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>                                
        php_admin_flag engine Off                                  
    </Directory>                                                   
</IfModule>
```

I think now you know what to do.

Comment: now /etc/apache2/mods-available/php8.0.conf

Answer (score 2):

Try the following actions:

- Make sure `mod_userdir` is enabled (`a2enmod userdir`).
- The `$HOME` and `public_html` dirs have the right read permissions.

  ```
  sudo -Hu SOMEUSER sh -c 'chmod 755 $HOME $HOME/public_html'
  ```
- Make sure `php_admin_value engine` is `On`.

  ```
  sudo vim /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*.conf
  ```

  Then find the line containing `php_admin_flag` and change it to:

  ```
  php_admin_flag engine On
  ```

  This is due that PHP is disabled by default for user dirs for Apache 2.

---

In your particular case, you've to uncomment the following lines:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /var/zpanel/hostdata/*/public_html/*>
        php_admin_value engine On
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mention by @kenorb, this is because PHP is disabled `php_admin_value engine Off` by default in userdirs for Apache2.

But instead of changing the `php_admin_value engine` to `On` in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php*.conf`, it is advised in the `.conf` file itself that the lines starting from `<IfModule>` to `</IfModule>` be commented out, so that `.htaccess` can handle the setting separately. This can be done as shown below:

```
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```